# What exactly happens when a class is stored in a different reference variable?

Tags: java, inheritance

Lets say that for example `VolksWagen extends Car`

and then we do the following

`Car abc = new VolksWagen();`

What exactly happens here?

If for example `VolksWagen()` has certain methods, `abc` will not have any of those methods, because, well, VolksWagen is the child and Car is the parent so the parent doesn't inherit any methods from its child.. however, I would like to know what the difference would be between

`Car abc = new VolksWagen();`

and

`Car def = new Car();`

Comment: That's not correct, abc will have those methods, they just aren't visible. Kind of like looking at a car from afar, you might not know the actual mark of the car, but you'll know it has 4 tires. If you would cast it back to Volkswagen (i.e. take a closer look) it will have the methods.

Comment: @kayaman that is the best analogy I have heard for this in a long time.

Comment: +1 @Kayaman - great description of the issue

Comment: @Kayaman, if `abc` will have those methods, and they arent visible, is there a way to change this?

Comment: @Elmedin you can cast it to the child class but often thats a sign of bad design and shouldn't usually be necessary

Answer (score 2):

When you extend Car, your brand new class VolksWagen inherits all of its methods. This means that it has at least all of the methods defined in Car.

Since WolksVagen has *at least* the methods in Car, it is considered okay to assign it to a variable of type Car, since calling any method on the class Car will also work on the VolksWagen object.

This allows you to write other methods that work on any Car, for example

```
void smash(Car car) {
   // ....
}
Car c = new VolksWagen();
smash(c); // Okay since c has all of Car's methods
```

It's worth noting that no methods are "lost" by this assignment, however they are not accessible using the variable `c`. You may cast it back to a VolksWagen object at any time using `VolksWagen v = (VolksWagen)c;`

Answer (score 0):

A `Volkswagen` is still a `Volkswagen` even if you store it in a `Car` variable.
You can cast `abc` to `VolksWagen` and then have access to its methods.

You can't cast `def` to `VolksWagen`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `Car` would be an abstract base class so you wouldn't be able to instantiate it directly. The benefit is that you can handle any type of `Car` in your code and simply call `drive()` for example without having to know the exact type. The `drive` method for each of the subclasses can then do something a little different (for example consume different amounts of gas per mile).

Also, don't get hung up on the class that you assign an instance to. That's just an artifact of how staticly-typed languages like Java work. It's easier to just think:

```
var car = new Volkswagon();
var car2 = new Honda();
car.drive();
car2.drive();
performOilChange(car);
performOilChange(car2);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you say Parent a = new Child() then it's a child.  When you say Parent a = new Parent() you can't use the child types because the parent doesn't inherit them.  If you say Child a = new Child() then you can use the parent method because of extension.

Comment: You just have to make a cast in order to use the child's method in that case, I would add.

Comment: @Renan but that's very rarely nessisary. Its usually a sign of bad design

Comment: Casting is only necessary for when you have a built in function that doesn't return the value you want.  Otherwise, steer clear of them because it's slow.  Just casting it during initialization is fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

We can talk so much about this but here is major difference:

`Car abc = new VolksWagen();`

You have access to all methods of Car, however if methods are overriden in `VolksWagen` they are invoked.

and

`Car def = new Car();`

Only methods of `Car` are invoked.

Cheers !!